# QSvgRenderer support issue

Tags: qt, svg, clip-path

Qt(even Qt6) QSvgRenderer can not supports SVG(a.k.a clippath)

Qt website says:

```
Qt supports the static features of SVG 1.2 Tiny. ECMA scripts and DOM manipulation are currently not supported.
```

Is there another way to insert SVG（or Vector Graphics in PDF）to PDF,pdfbox? inkscape?
thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to add SVG items to PDF use QPDFWriter, but i found it impossible, cause QSvgRenderer can not supports SVG?

Answer (score 0):

You could use QtWebEngine. There is a print handler example in the documentation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-printme-example.html